# Parsing one lined text file and separating it by delimiters

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am having an issue with long one lined text files when it comes to parsing them in batch, specifically with the 1024 character limitation because I am setting a variable to be the contents of the file and it will only grab 1024 of the first characters.

I am wanting to split my text file by a set delimiter (I am using ~ as my delimiter) onto a new line and output the results to another text file.
The file coming in would look like:

```
line1~line2~line3~line4~etc~
```

All the way up to for example 5000 characters. I would like the results to look like:

```
line1~
line2~
line3~
line4~
etc~
```

Here is my current code:

```
@echo off
set /p input=<input.txt
call :parse "%input%"
pause
goto :eof

:parse
setlocal
set var=%~1
for /F "tokens=* delims=~" %%a in ("%var%") do (
    if not "%%a" == "" call :splitVar "%%a"
    if not "%%b" == "" call :parse "%%b"
)
endlocal
pause
goto :eof

:splitVar
setlocal
echo %~1
set filename=%~1
goto :eof
```

Is there any way to overcome the limitation of 1024 characters or some way to parse it this way?

Also, let me know if this question is against the rules in any way. I'm kind of new to stackoverflow.

Comment: There is a bit of a learning curve, but have you considered using something like [PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx), which is much more powerful than command shell scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q2904836.txt) DO call :parse "%%a"
pause
goto :eof

:parse
setlocal
set var=%~1
:parseloop
IF DEFINED var for /F "tokens=1* delims=~" %%a in ("%var%") do (
    if not "%%a" == "" call :splitVar "%%a"&SET "var=%%b"&GOTO parseloop
)
endlocal
pause
goto :eof

:splitVar
setlocal
echo %~1
set filename=%~1
goto :eof
```

I used a file named `q2904836.txt` containing some data for my testing.

There is a limit to the extent of the stack, and you are calling `:parse` for each entry in your line, which will blow the limit.

Note the use of `tokens=1*`, assigning the next token to `%%a` abd the remainder-of-line to `%%b`.

Using the `for/f` in the manner demonstrated will overcome the 1024 limit - but there's still a limit of a little over 8100 characters.

Note also that your `setlocal/endlocal` in `:parse` and setlocal/implicit-endlocal in ':splitvar` will mean that the variables that may have been established or changed in those routines will be discarded.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. I found that I had to modify it slightly to accept special characters. Unfortunately it seems that I ran into the issue with the 8100 character limit with a file that has a whopping 179708 characters. I may have to look into somehow limiting it to only run with files with a length 8100 characters or shorter, or finding another solution to overcome this (possibly using another language).

Answer (score 0):

The limit is not at 1024, it's at 8191.

The splitting works a bit different than you thought.

It splits to multiple tokens, but you need some other solution.

You can replace all - signs with linefeeds, than you get the desired result.

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set LF=^


for %%a in ("!LF!") do set var=!var:-=%%a!
For /f "delims=" %%a in ("!var!") Do echo %%a
```

Comment: Um - not so. The `set var=<filename` method chokes on lines longer than 1024 chars.